# The limit of weighted partial sums

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f_n(k)$ be a function defined on $k\in\{0,1,2,\dots,n\}$, such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(k)=f(k)$ uniformly and $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}f(k)=0$.

Also, let $w_n(k)$ be a weight function such that $\sum_{k=1}^n w_n(k)=1$,

I'd like to argue that, if
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}w_n(k)=0,$$
then
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^nw_n(k)f_n(k)=0.$$

If we take $f_n(k)=f(k)$ and $w_n(k)=1/n$, I think it will be reduced to the Cesaro means and the proof is obvious.

Can anybody help me prove the generalized version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, saying $f_n\to f$ uniformly makes no sense because $f_n$ is not defined on all of the domain of $f$. But we all know what you mean. This is very simple, if you "choose" this and that in the right order.

Let $\epsilon>0$. Choose $K$ so $|f(k)|<\epsilon$ for all $k\ge K$. Choose $N>K$ so $|f_n(k)-f(k)|<\epsilon$ for all $k\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ if $n>N$. Then
$$\sum_{k=K}^n|f_n(k)-f(k)|w_{n,k}<2\epsilon\quad(n>N),$$while
$$\sum_{k=K}^n|f(k)|w_{n,k}<\epsilon$$ for all $n$.

And it's clear that $$\sum_{k=1}^{K-1}|f_n(k)|w_{n,k}
\le \sum_{k=1}^{K-1}(|f(k)|+1)w_{n,k}<\epsilon$$if $n$ is large enough.

Comment: Thank you so much! But doesn't this mean that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^nw_n(k)f_n(k)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^nw_n(k)f(k)$? How can I know $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^nw_n(k)f_n(k)=0$?

Comment: There are three inequalities above. Use the fact that $|f_n(k)|\le|f(k)|+|f(k)-f_n(k)|$ to put two of them together, and you see that $\sum|f_n(k)|w_n(k)<\epsilon$ if $n$ is large enough...

Comment: Oh I got it! Thank you so much.

Comment: Ok, then this is when you click on that little check mark to "accept" the answer...